# Como acessar informações de um arquivo .torrent?

Tags: php, bittorrent

Gostaria de saber se é possível e como obter informações (*magnet link, seedes, leechers, peers*, tamanho, etc..) de um arquivo **.torrent** utilizando PHP.

Comment: Eu votei para reabrir e me arrependi. Basta utilizar o Google, vários resultados são apresentados, basta escolher. É um problema trivialmente resolvido com uma busca no Google.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira então se existe o Google, nenhuma pergunta aqui no *SOpt* precisa existir. A ideia é agregar conteúdo relevante no site, e esta é uma dúvida que não existe por aqui ainda.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues essa talvez seja uma discussão para o meta, que não pretendo levar adiante. Mas não, o Google não é capaz de responder todas as perguntas de desenvolvimento. Disso eu não tenho dúvida.

Comment: Google serve para a pessoa pelo menos começar uma lógica de desenvolvimento que esta faltando aqui, na minha primeira busca pelo assunto achei https://github.com/adriengibrat/torrent-rw

Comment: A pergunta foi reaberta após a abertura de [discussão no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3739/amplo-demais-qual-o-problema-desta-pergunta). @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira O fato de a resposta existir no Google não quer dizer que ela não tenha espaço aqui. A não ser que a pergunta seja ampla demais (por exemplo, caso a resposta seja a documentação completa de uma ferramenta) ou tenha outro tipo de problema. O simples fato de haver respostas em outros lugares não invalida a pergunta aqui.

Comment: Outra coisa @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: favor não postar links para o lmgtfy (eles soam meio pejorativos, não acha?)

Comment: @Otto Mesmo que essa lib resolva o problema, ela está em Inglês e não apresenta nenhuma informação contextual de *como*  ou *porque* funciona. Se fazemos tanta questão que as pessoas queiram aprender as coisas, evitar que apenas "copiem e colem" trechos de código na internet é o melhor caminho. E aqui nós podemos ter respostas muito mais completas e técnicas.

Comment: @Gabe repassei o link para ajudar como estava sem tempo para montar um exemplo plausível. e ser menos "legal" que o outro amigo que mandou pesquisar no google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um arquivo de **torrent** contém apenas metadados, que são informações sobre o arquivo de destino mas nenhuma informação de conteúdo deste arquivo final. É basicamente um dicionário de [bencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode), que como [neste exemplo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquivo_de_Torrent#Arquivo_.C3.BAnico), contém essa estrutura:

```
{
     'announce': 'http://bttracker.debian.org:6969/announce',
     'info':
     {
         'name': 'debian-503-amd64-CD-1.iso',
         'piece length': 262144,
         'length': 678428672,
         'pieces': '841ae846bc5b6d7bd6e9aa3dd9e551559c82abc1...d14f1631d776008f83772ee170c42411618190a4'
     }
}
```

Apenas um dos exemplos que você pode encontrar por aí, com [esta classe](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3473-PHP-Parse-and-extract-metadata-from-BitTorrent-files.html) você consegue extrair estes dados de um arquivo **torrent**, basta implementar algo assim para visualizar:

```
require_once 'class.bdecode.php';

$torrent = new BDecode('arquivo.torrent');
$results = $torrent->result;
```

Onde `$results` contém a estrutura de dicionário que citei um exemplo mais acima.

Como você pode observar, somente alguns destes dados que você citou estão incluídos no arquivo como o *nome*, *partes*, *tamanho* e etc, então isso responde parcialmente sua pergunta. Em relação aos *seeds*, *peers* e etc, isso vai além dos metadados do arquivo, pois envolve todo o protocolo de comunicação **P2P**.

Answer (score 2):

Existe a biblioteca [libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/) em C++.

Porém ela fornece também uma [interface python](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/python_binding.html#using-libtorrent-in-python) caso voce seja mais confortável com esta linguagem.

```
import libtorrent
info = libtorrent.torrent_info('test.torrent')
for f in info.files():
    print "%s - %s" % (f.path, f.size)
```

*[Fonte: SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406809/1449839)*

Comment: O OP quer uma resposta para PHP.

Comment: @OlimonF. Quando respondi, no dia 29/04 as 17:59, não havia esta informação, pois ela foi editada 29/04 às 18:20